# Проблема с Gradle, при создании Android приложения на Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle

Скачал исходный код приложения и тут же возникли проблемы с Gradle. При попытке синхронизации приложения вылетает ошибка следующего содержания:

```
Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.sources.DefaultKotlinSourceSetKt
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чем это связано и что с этим делать

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60833542/7540461

Comment: @Tiarait, спасибо, помогло